# How do I calculate the number of days using MonthCalendar in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, date-range, monthcalendar

I have added the calendar form and it won't let me select 2 dates.  It assigns every click to the start date so when I try this it always tells me the difference is 1 and the start date is always changed to whatever my next click is?

Is it possible to have it default to today's date for the start date and then have every other click determine the end date?  When I tried to assign today's date within the `datechanged` event handler it wouldn't let me change the month because it kept focusing on the `startdate`?

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    numDays = Convert.ToInt32((monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd - monthCalendar1.SelectionStart).TotalDays);
    MessageBox.Show("num " + numDays);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Sets the Month Calenders Min & Max to days in current month.
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime lastDay = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month));

dateMonthCalender.MinDate = firstDay;
dateMonthCalender.MaxDate = lastDay;
```

The above will set min and max to days in current month

If you want to set the min to today

```
dateMonthCalender.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Can we have more details please, whats your goal, if your in the selection changed event you probably should pass your selection to a method and do whatever your trying to do outside of the event.

Comment: When I input that code it still assigns each click as the start date:

Comment: it will because your inside the DateChanged event

Comment: private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {   DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            DateTime lastDay = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month));
            monthCalendar1.MinDate = firstDay;
            monthCalendar1.MaxDate = lastDay;
            numDays = Convert.ToInt32((monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd - monthCalendar1.SelectionStart).TotalDays);
            MessageBox.Show("selection " + monthCalendar1.SelectionStart);
        }

Comment: How do I get it to assign my click to the dateEnd date so that my calculation can determine the number of days between dates selected?

Comment: I am trying to use the calendar so that a user can click a date after todays date and it will determine how many days from today until that clicked date

Comment: So setting the mindate is not working as when I click another date that becomes the start date.  Is there any way for it to permanently assign the start date and then and subsequent click is the end date?

Comment: The code i gave you, will give you the desired result, stop focusing on the selection and more on what you are trying to do, all you need to do is subtract today from dateselected, pass them to a method and assign the result to a varable or write them to a line or do a messagebos.show. Each time you select a day in  the calender, it will assign that value to SELECTEDDAY.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so declare two ints and assign one to selected day and the other to today and create yourself a method

```
 int selectedDay;
 int todayValue;

DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0);

DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
     string todayShort = today.ToShortDateString();
     string thisDay = todayShort.Substring(0, 2);

     todayValue = Convert.ToInt32(thisDay);

private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
  {
     // Shorten date format to day and assign it.
     string dMC = dateMonthCalender.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
     string takeDMCDay = dMC.Substring(0, 2);
     selectedDay = Convert.ToInt32(takeDay);
```

}